# Why is the successor of a BST node defined as the one larger than the deleted one?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

In the following image, if I add 14 to the right side of 12,  then 14 can replace the 15 without influencing other nodes, just like the correct answer 16. Why the successor is defined to use the number that is bit larger than it not the one that is a bit smaller?
[image]

Comment: Well, "successor" implies it comes afterwards, not before. But you could just as well move the predecessor when you delete; unless you're using the BST as a min-priority queue in which case the node you're deleting never has a predecessor. You might prefer to move one or the other depending on which will keep the tree more balanced, but you will often have to rebalance either way.

Comment: its inorder successor. this is one approach. you can do use predecessor as well

Comment: where is 14 in your original tree? Its not there. How can you replace 15 with 14?

Comment: Consider accepting an answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in terms of language, `successor` is the one that comes right after, implying that it must be bigger.

In terms of the deleting algorithm, you can use both the successor and the predecessor to replace the deleted node.

`Successor`: is the smallest node in the right subtree of the deleted node, which means that it is the smallest node that is bigger than the deleted node, so you guarantee that, if you replace the deleted node with it, it will still be smaller than every other node in the right subtree, so it won't break any property.

`Predecessor`: is the biggest node in the left subtree of the deleted node, which means that it is the biggest node that is smaller than the deleted node, so you guarantee that, if you replace the deleted node with it, it will still be bigger than every other node in the left subtree, so it won't break any property.

In a nutshell, you can use the successor or the predecessor without any problems, is not a question of definition, only a question of choice.